# error on poll function Java Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

This my Consumer Class. Alaways I have error on poll function 'The method poll(long) in the type KafkaConsumer<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Duration)' and on fetching the records 'Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable'. I m using JDK 1.8.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;  
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;  
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;  
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;  
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;  
import org.slf4j.Logger;  
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;  
  
import java.time.Duration;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties; 
public class KaConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(KaConsumer.class.getName());  
        String bootstrapServers="127.0.0.1:9092";  
        String grp_id="My_App";  
        String topic="Tweet01";
        Properties properties=new Properties();  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServers);  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,   StringDeserializer.class.getName());  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,grp_id);  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");

      //creating consumer  
        KafkaConsumer<String,String> Consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(properties);
        Consumer.subscribe("Tweet01");

        
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<Integer,String> records=Consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));  
            for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record: records){  
            System.out.println(record);
            }
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The method poll(long) in the type KafkaConsumer<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Duration)'

The error is telling you to replace `Duration.ofMillis(100)` with `100`. You can upgrade your client version if you want to use Duration

> Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

The for loop looks okay, `ConsumerRecords` does implement the Iterable interface, but you have a type mismatch in the key

FWIW, if the purpose is to only print the records, I'd suggest Kafka Streams or another higher level library

Answer (score 0):

Notice your ConsumerRecords<Integer,String>
Instead of <String,String>